# python gspread library only writes to worksheet labeled 'sheet1'

Tags: python, worksheet, gspread

My sheet is named 'doc_name', and it has two worksheets, 'sheet1' and 'sheet2'. but, i can only write data to the worksheet labeled 'sheet1'?

is this a limitation or am i doing something wrong?

this works,

```
wks = gc.open("doc_name").sheet1
```

but this fails,

```
wks = gc.open("doc_name").sheet2
```

giving this error,

**AttributeError: 'Spreadsheet' object has no attribute 'sheet2'**

i also notice that this fails,

wks = gc.open("doc_name").**S**heet1

...where i use a capital 'S'.. and it will only write if i specify lowercase .**s**heet1

how do i write to a worksheet without having to code... wks = gc.open("doc_name").sheet1?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This is because `gspread` only implemented `sheet1` to let you retrieve the first sheet in your spreadsheet **as a shortcut**.

From the [source code](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/models.py#L73-L76)  you can see the implementation of `sheet1` is using `get_worksheet(0)`

```
@property
def sheet1(self):
    """Shortcut property for getting the first worksheet."""
    return self.get_worksheet(0)
```

So if you want to retrieve other sheets, you need to use other methods like:

1.specify *index* as a integer indicating the position of the sheet to open starting from 0:

`wks = gc.open("doc_name").get_worksheet(index)`

or

2.specify *title* of the sheet to open as a string:

`wks = gc.open("doc_name").worksheet(title)`

That is to say, in you case, to get sheet2 you can probably use

`wks = gc.open("doc_name").get_worksheet(1)`

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, i've had some trouble with gsheets lately. my biggest problem is in this post where i'm having connection time out issues, would you know an answer to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596661/python-gspread-connection-time-out-when-writing-to-google-sheets

Comment: @user3768071sorry I don't have a good suggestion for that issue. I will get back to you at the time I can figure out one

Answer (score 5):

```
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open('name').worksheet('name/title')
```