# How to Access Different Google Sheets From Python?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So I have Python basically connected to google sheets at the moment. It can access the first sheet and read and write data:

```py
sheet = client.open("Remake").sheet1
```

I can access sheet 1 inside the overarching spreadsheet, but I cannot access the second sheet (sheet2) by just changing it to:

```py
sheet = client.open("Remake").sheet2
```

Comment: Kindly accept my answer if this is helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

To explain this, it is because Google Spreadsheet only implemented `sheet1` to let you retrieve the first sheet in your spreadsheet as a shortcut. So if you want to retrieve other sheets, you need to use other methods like:

```
wks = gc.open("doc_name").get_worksheet(index)
```

or

```
wks = gc.open("doc_name").worksheet(title)
```

Related infos:

- [repo](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/blob/master/gspread/models.py#L73-L76)
- [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570749/python-gspread-library-only-writes-to-worksheet-labeled-sheet1)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this code working (python 3.7)

```
Spreadsheet  = client.open("sheet_name").worksheet("sheet_title")
```