# How to access another page in a spreadsheet?

Tags: python, gspread

I'm not sure how to access another page in a spreadsheet.

[image]

I have multiple pages of a spreadsheet and I want to migrate approved rows to the approved to the next page, but I'm not sure how to access the other pages. Any help is appreciated, this is also my first stack overflow post. :)

My code so far:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import pprint

#Authorize the API
scope = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'
    ]
file_name = 'client_key.json'
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(file_name,scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

#Fetch the sheet
formResponses = client.open('Raid Points').sheet1
approved = client.open('approved').sheet1
python_sheet = formResponses.get_all_records()
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()

def uuidToIndex(uuid):
    for i in range(uuids.len()):
        if uuids[i]==uuid:
            return i
    return -1

#def updateUuids():
    

stopCell = formResponses.cell(2,7).value
        
uuids=[]

#while stopCell==false:
```

Comment: Look at URL line of your browser, it's different for different pages

Comment: I thought that this thread might be the answer for your question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/33570749/7108653

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to access a specific sheet by name:

```
approved = client.open('Raid Points').worksheet('approved')
```